# Equivalent of Python scipy.signal.correlate in C# or C++

Tags: python, c#, c++, fft, correlation

I have code in Python that searches for matching a small audio file within a large audio file. For this purpose it uses the `scipy.signal.correlate` function, I searched for an equivalent function in C# or C++, but I did not find it.

I can translate all the code to C# except for the `scipy.signal.correlate` function.

How can you implement a similar function in C# or C++?

```
import datetime
from scipy import signal
import numpy as np
import librosa

def seconds2str(seconds):
    return str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=seconds))

def find_templ(src_path, templ_path):

    samples_src, sample_rate = librosa.load(src_path, sr=None)
    samples_templ, sample_rate_templ = librosa.load(templ_path, sr=sample_rate)
    src_duration = librosa.get_duration(y=samples_src, sr=sample_rate)
    templ_duration = librosa.get_duration(y=samples_templ, sr=sample_rate_templ)

    if templ_duration > src_duration:
        print("warning: You are looking for a clip within an audio clip shorter than it!!!")

    print(f"src   Duration: {seconds2str(src_duration)}")
    print(f"templ Duration: {seconds2str(templ_duration)}")

    correlate = signal.correlate(samples_src[:sample_rate * int(src_duration)], samples_templ, mode='valid', method='fft')
    start = np.round(np.argmax(correlate) / sample_rate, 2)
    end = start + templ_duration
    print(f"The moment the search stops in seconds: {seconds2str(src_duration)}")
    print(f"Start: {seconds2str(start)}")
    print(f"End:   {seconds2str(end)}")


full_audio = "Track08.mp3"
small_audio = "adv.wav"
find_templ(full_audio, small_audio)
```

Comment: why c# OR c++? Which one are you using? C# can use any .net libraries and with C++, you might as well just shell out to python

Comment: I think it's probably already implemented in c in scipy: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/main/scipy/signal/_correlate_nd.c.in

Comment: @GarrGodfrey I using `C#` and can also use `C++` within `.NET`, but do not use Python.

Comment: @AlanBirtles The code there is not compilable, it is not normal C code.

Comment: There are many, many libraries for signal processing. Any one of them will have a function as basic as correlation.

Comment: I didn't say it was, but it might be better than writing it yourself and I imagine as part of the build process it is changed into standard c code